# Django field refering to another field

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-views

I'm about to make a Django model with conditions. I've thought about these fields

```
class Condition(models.Model):
    model_name = CharField(max_length=100)
    field_name = CharField(max_length=100)
    value = CharField(max_length=100)
```

So I can create a condition where a specific field (`field_name`) in a specific model (`model_name`) is equal to `value`. But I thought there might be a solution for this already? Instead of using `field_name` I thought if it was possible to refer directly to the field either through `ContentType` or something else?

Comment: Are you referring to [generic foreign keys](http://axiacore.com/blog/how-use-genericforeignkey-django/)?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very high level and the code does not exactly model what you were asking.  But they are simple examples from a

Django Signals to determine when a change happened.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Here is a signals.py file in my app for managing Person objects when Users change:

```
from django.db import models
from anotherapp.models import *

def user_post_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        if instance.username:
            person_item = Person.objects.get(username = instance.username)
            person_item.django_user = None
            person_item.save()
    except:
        pass

def user_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        if instance.username:
            p, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(
                username=instance.username)
            p.django_user = instance
            p.save()
    except:
        pass

models.signals.post_delete.connect(user_post_delete, sender=User)
models.signals.post_save.connect(user_post_save, sender=User)
```

Django ContentTypes to relate your condition to the object in question.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Here is an model I am using with ContentTypes:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
class Comment(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    #removed fields not relevent
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField('date_added',auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('date_updated',auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True, editable=False)
```

Then in your views.py/signals.py to use that ContentType model(Ticket is a model name, and t.id is the id of the Ticket object:

```
new_comment = Comment(
    message = "test message",
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model='Ticket'),
    object_id = t.id,
)
new_comment.save()
```

You would then want to expand to have a simple boolean as to if your condition was met, or get a bit more into it and use another model to store results and come up with a "5

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Django's [models.ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) doc.

Comment: Foreign keys refers to other objects. I want to refer to fields.